# python distribution build with specific wxpython library version

Tags: python, wxpython, libraries, py2exe

I am trying to create a python software distribution depending on wxpython library. The thing is that I have two different versions in my PC: 2.8 and 3.0. The tool I use for exe creation is py2exe and the following content in setup.py :

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(
  name='Grabador tarjetas',
  version='0.0',
  description='Grabador Mifare',
  author='siteco.desarrollo',
  author_email='siteco.desarrollo@gmail.com',
  url='http://www.sitecosl.net',
  scripts=["GrabadorTarjetaMifareSiteco.py"],
  windows=["GrabadorTarjetaMifareSiteco.py"],
  data_files=[('', ['config.cfg'])],
  install_requires=["wxpython=wx-2.8-msw-unicode"]
  )
```

Each time I generate exe file, instead of including wxpython 2.8 library, it gets 3.0 library, regarding wxpython. Then, when I launch exe application, I get an error due to the difference between included library and needed library.

In my python distribution folder, inside lib/site-packages, I have two folders for wxpython distributions: wx-2.8-msw-unicode and wx-3.0-msw. Besides, wx.pth is pointing  to wx-2.8-msw-unicode. Running from pydev in eclipse works fine, but I get errors when executing generated exe from "dist" folder.

Obviously something is wrong....
¿Could you give me any tips?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution: in my main script, I have included the following code

```
import sys

if not hasattr(sys, 'frozen'):
    import wxversion
    wxversion.select('2.8')
```

setup.py remains the same.

Thanks.